# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4effffff

Tags: c++, access-violation

This problem got me crazy, I have searched in web but couldn't find any answer related to my problem .
The error is this:

> Unhandled exception at 0x7726dfe4 in GraphSimulation.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation reading location 0x4effffff.

I have a main project called GraphSimulation which simulates a network. This GraphSimulator generates a network object.

```
class CNetwork
{
private:

    //...
    unsigned long                   lastTimeUnitStepCounter;
    NetworkObjectCode               codeGenerationCounter;
    vector <string>                 HBInfo;
    SStatisticsMonitor              statisticMonitor;

    bool                            bManageCashAlone;


private:
    void TrySendingMoviePartsOnPath();
    void InitActionArrayWithNetwork();


public:

    void                            SetHalfBallInfo( string );
    vector<string>                  GetHalfBallInfo();
```

and I have another project which is the algorithm for the network to help how to distribute movies.

I need to set some information when algorithm runs.

```
string s = "some information";

network.SetHalfBallInfo(s);
```

SetHalfBallInfo stores this information in HBInfo; and I need to display it in GUI when algorithm finishes running. So GetHalfBallInfo calls the information.

```
m_HalfBallInfo = _network.GetHalfBallInfo();

//showing the movie parts list
CListBox* pSolutionDisplayList = (CListBox*)GetDlgItem(IDC_SOLUTION_LIST);

for(int i = 0 ; i < m_HalfBallInfo.size() ; ++ i )
    {   
        CString str;
        str.Format("%u " , m_HalfBallInfo[i]);
        pSolutionDisplayList->AddString(str);
    }
```

But it crashes when I return network before starting algorithm run.

```
CNetwork CGraphView::ConvertGraphToNetwork()
{
    CNetwork network;

    //...

    for(int i = 0 ; i < movieCodeArray.GetSize() ;  ++i)
    {
        CMovieWrapper currMovieWrapper;
        pDlgParam->movieList.GetNetworkObject(movieCodeArray[i] , &currMovieWrapper);
        network.AddMovie(currMovieWrapper.GetMovieCopy());
    }

    //...         


    return network;
}
```

Crashes after return network. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should show us the exact code that crashes, because I don't think its in there.

Comment: Have you tired runnig it in a debugger? You are accessing memory that you shouldn't be accessing, but it's hard to say exactly why or where.

Comment: On which line exactly is it crashing, and how are the variables used in that line set up?

Comment: Please run your program in the debugger. It will stop when the crash happens, at the location of the crash. You can then walk up/down the function call stack and examine variables etc. At least you can then help us to help you by pointing out *where* the crash happens.

Comment: after "return network;" in the code I added above it enters to afxtempl.h

Comment: If, for some reason, you can not debug code, then generate MAP file and look for the function placed at the address 0x7726dfe4. Seems you work on Windows, and I suppose you build using VC++ IDE.

Comment: -1: immediate downvote to any question with a crash that doesn't include the backtrace. Why should we waste time guessing?

Comment: Are you sure your implementation of CNetwork's copy constructor is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Passing Network class as a return value is quite heavy and may have multiple side effects.
What you actually do is define a new object at the beginning of the function, add some stuff to it, then copy it to an intermediate instance at the end of the function and destroy the original one. This could be devastating if you have dynamically allocated elements in this class, and don't copy construct them properly (and if you do - it's very inefficient).

It's hard to tell if that's the problem without seeing the entire code, but regardless of that - you should consider passing pointers back and forth (or references, although that may cause other errors if you're not careful)